# Projective resolution of a quiver with relations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, derived-categories

How do we compute the projective resolution of a representation of a quiver with relations.

For example consider the Beilinson quiver $B_4$

[image]$.

with the relations ­$\{\alpha_j^k\alpha_i^{k-1}=\alpha_i^k\alpha_j^{k-1}:1\leq i,j\leq 4,1\leq k\leq 3\}$

Since the Beilinson quiver $B_4$ is derived equivalent to the $\mathfrak{D}^b(\mathbb{P}^3)$, it has finite projective dimension. How do we construct the projective resolution for a representation of this quiver?